# How to create SQL DB project in Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015

When I try to create new SQL Server Database Project in Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web, i get this error:

### [image: vs 2015 error]

Could not louad file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser', Version=14.100.0.0,...

I have installed SQL Server 2014 and 2016. Visual Studio 2015 is updated to latest version. I tried reinstall. Also try to install Microsoft SQL Server Feature Pack.

Packages:

- SharedManagementObjects.msi
- SQLSysClrTypes.msi
- TSqlLanguageService.msi
- and others.

Comment: I looked at version list of SQL Servers, and version 14.100.0.0 is not there.

https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.cz/

Comment: Maybe is broken after install update of Visual Studio 2015.